# Grep get everything except matching

Tags: bash, regex, grep

Lets say I have a text file that says:

```
Hello my name is agz.
I am asking a question that is important.
```

If i type: `grep -v "is" /path/to/file`, I should get no output because both lines have "is".

If i type: `grep -o "is" /path/to/file`, i should get:

```
is
is
```

However I want to get:

```
Hello my name agz.
I am asking a question that important.
```

(just missing the is) Is there a way to achieve this using grep and minimal regex?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`grep` isn't the right tool for this job. `sed` is.

```
$ sed 's|is||g' test.txt
Hello my name  agz.
I am asking a question that  important.

$ sed 's|is ||g' test.txt
Hello my name agz.
I am asking a question that important.
```